# Is there a way to specify a generic function which only accepts one of two specific types?

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols

I have a few functions that are identical except for the fact that they handle two different types. I wish to keep my code more DRY so I would like to turn them into one function for two types. But how do I do that?

I know how to create a generic function: `func doSomething<T>(arg: T) { ... }`

I also know how to create a generic function that only accepts objects of a certain protocol:

`func doSomething<T: Event>(arg: T) { ... }`

Now I've solved this little problem before when I wanted a function that would accept both Strings and objects that conform to the Event protocol. In that case I solved it quite easily by just making String conform to the Event protocol like so: `extension String: Event {}`. (Event is an empty protocol anyway)

But this time the two types I'm dealing with are `String` and `Event.Type`. And in that case I can't use the same trick, because meta-types cannot be extended or be used to extend other types with.

Is there a way to write something like this?

`func doSomething<T where T == Event.Type || T == String>(arg: T) { ... }`

### Edit, I'll explain more why I'm doing this:

I'm writing an event-dispatcher. Events can either be a string like "user.birthday" accompanied with a payload or an object that conforms to the Event protocol. I want to support both, because different developers have different preferences. So I can define events and listeners like so:

```
struct UserWonAward: Event {
    let user: User
}

events.listenTo("user.birthday") {
    (user: User) in
    print("Happy birthday \(user.name)!")
}

events.listenTo {
    (event: UserWonAward) in
    print("Congratulations \(event.user.name)!")
}
```

And now here comes the thing I want help with. Sometimes I'll line up a few events in a queue and then later flush the queue of a specific type, like so:

```
let user1 = User(name: "John Doe")
let user2 = User(name: "Jane Doe")

events.queue("user.birthday", payload: user1)
events.queue("user.birthday", payload: user2)

events.queue(UserWonAward(user: user1))
events.queue(UserWonAward(user: user2))

// Some time later

events.flushQueueOf("user.birthday")
events.flushQueueOf(UserWonAward)
```

As you can see, in that `flushQueueOf()` method I can input either a `String` or an `Event.Type`. Right now I have written two separate methods for that, but the code in those two methods are nearly identical so I really want to merge them into one method.

Comment: Do you want the function to accept `String` or `String.Type`? I'm trying to understand the purpose of this

Comment: I want the function to accept `String` and `Event.Type`. I edited my post to make it more clear. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Can you have 2 methods, one that accepts `String` and one that accepts `Event.Type`. Then use those 2 public methods to delegate to a 3rd (private) method that holds the identical code?

Comment: That might make sense if the functions were long, but in this case they're all between 1 and 3 lines of code. So yeah adding another function then would only make my code bigger.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can have type *intersections* - ie "and" logic (where the type is bound by multiple types), but you can't have a *union* - ie "or" logic like you want.

If you think about it, it doesn't make sense, especially with java's type safety.

If your method works with either of two types, and you want to follow DRY:

```
public void method(TypeA x) {
    methodAnyType(x);
}

public void method(TypeB x) {
    methodAnyType(x);
}

private void methodAnyType(Object x) {
    // x is either TypeA or TypeB
}
```